# QueryException for visible managed package field?

Tags: apex, soql, query, exception, platform-bug

I've got a basic query that references fields in a managed package. The field is visible to all profiles, and the object has view all perms for all profiles. But throws this query exception

> No such column 'zqu__Deleted__c' on entity 'zqu__ProductRatePlan__c'.
>   If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the
>   '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

If I change add `without sharing` to the class making the query the issue goes away. I'm also able to do a query, `SELECT zqu__Deleted__c FROM zqu__ProductRatePlan__c LIMIT 1`, from the dev console without errors.

I'd very much prefer to leave `without sharing` off so profile changes for the objects CRUD are respected. Any idea what else I should be doing to avoid this exception?